# Jquery not showing button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, show

Trying to show the submit button when the login fails, but unable to show it.

My Code:-

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" ></script>
  <style>
    .hiddenFramehideclass {
      position: absolute;
      top: -1px;
      left: -1px;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" class="needs-validation" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginform" target="hiddenFrame">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <hr />
    <label for="emailid">Email: </label>
    <input id="emailid" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="txtulogindetail" required />
    <br /><br /><br />
    <label for="passwordid">Password: </label>
    <input id="passwordid" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="txtupass" required />
    <hr />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn-login" id="loginsubmitbutton">Sign in</button>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <span id="register_link"> <a href= "register">Register!</a></span>

    <hr />


  </form>

  <iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hiddenFramehideclass"></iframe>
</body>

<script>
  /*Submit Button Clicked Function Starts */

  $("#loginsubmitbutton").click(function() {

    $("#loginsubmitbutton").hide(); //Hiding submit button
    $("#register_link").hide(); //Hiding Register Link

    /*Making Inputs to readonly Starts*/

    $("input").css({
      'pointer-events': 'none'
    });

    /*Making Inputs to readonly Ends*/


  });

  /*Submit Button Clicked Function Ends */
</script>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

$email = trim($_POST['txtulogindetail']); 
$password = trim($_POST['txtupass']); 

$stmt = $myclass->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email=:lrn LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindparam(":lrn",$email);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

if($myclass->login($email,$password)){
    echo '<script> alert("Logged In"); </script>';
}
else{
    echo '<script>         
        $("#loginsubmitbutton").show(); //Hiding submit button
        $("#register_link").show(); //Hiding Register Link 
        alert("Error");
        </script>';
}
}
else{
    echo '<script> alert("Email Not Found"); </script>';
}

}

?>


</html>
```

So when I try to login with the above codes:

1. It alerts **Logged In** when credentials are correct.
2. It **only** alerts **Error** when credentials are not correct (password incorrect) (But as per the code it should show the submit button again.)
3. It alerts **Email not found** when Email is not found

Comment: What happens when you close the alert? Can you the submit button then?

Comment: Nothing happens after I close the alert. No, I can't able to show the submit button again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is running in **iframe**. And your script wants to change the things in **parent**. For this you should tell the code where to be executed. (parent.$().......)

Below will help you to get the submit button.

```
echo '<script>         
    parent.$("#loginsubmitbutton").show(); //Hiding submit button
    parent.$("#register_link").show(); //Hiding Register Link 
    //alert("Error");
    </script>';
```

Comment: I think you've correctly identified the problem Will that solution actually work, though?

Comment: Yes, the solution parent.... works for me very well. @GarrGodfrey

Answer (score 0):

The thing is alert is first executed before any DOM manipulation. You have to wait for document ready.

Try something like this:

```php
echo '<script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#loginsubmitbutton").show(); //Hiding submit button
           $("#register_link").show(); //Hiding Register Link 
        });        
      </script>';
```

Also if you keep the alert, the DOM manipulation will take post closing the alert. So if you want to handle that you have to trigger some event and add a listener to alert.

Comment: The issue is not alert, the issue is: `$("#loginsubmitbutton").show(); $("#register_link").show(); //Hiding Register Link` here. I just added alerts to check if script is working or not.

Comment: Have you tried document ready? Just like I have updated in my answer

Comment: it's submitting to the iframe. so the javascript isn't going to run in the correct window